# Why MIT6.824 course lab2(raft) doesn't suggest us use time.timer?

Tags: go, time, distributed-system, raft

just like https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/labs/lab-raft.html wrote:

> Hint: You'll need to write code that takes actions periodically or after delays in time. The easiest way to do this is to create a goroutine with a loop that calls `time.Sleep()`; (see the ticker() goroutine that Make() creates for this purpose). Don't use Go's `time.Timer` or `time.Ticker`, which are difficult to use correctly.

Lab manual doesn't allow me to use `time.Timer` .

However,  I think that using `time.timer` and for-select state is the easiest method to construct `electionTimer` and `heartbeatTimer`. I just want to know why and what is the disadvantage of `time.Timer` in this lab.
Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.